# Generating all paths from CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, path

I want make a program using python that will generate all the possible paths from a csv file. How would I go about this?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def dataInCol(fieldName):
    df = pd.read_csv('..\\data.csv',usecols=[fieldName])
    qr = df.values.tolist()
    flattened = [val for sublist in qr for val in sublist]
    return flattened


def makingPaths(dataCol, path = "Companies: "):
    with open('..\\data.csv', "rb") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        headers = reader.fieldnames
    for eachValue in dataCol:
        path = path + str(eachValue)
        if str(eachValue) in headers:
            newCol = dataInCol(str(eachValue))
            makingPaths(newCol)
        break
    return path
```

For example in the image below:

Companies -> Apple -> iPhone -> iPhone4.0

Companies -> Samsung -> Gtablet -> SamTab7.0

...

Companies -> Sony -> Xperia -> Xperia4K

...
Link to data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11puxvQH6z6D3xiKybHEVbBpMp_Zv87LjlTd_ZIxYNw8/edit?usp=sharing

[CSV Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1yMH.jpg)

```
Companies   Apple   Samsung Sony    iPhone  Mac iPad    Galaxy  Notebook    Gtablet Xperia  Xtablet
Apple   iPhone  Galaxy  Xperia  iPhone4.0   Macbook iPadMini    GalaxyS3    NSeries5    SamTab7.0   Xperia4K    XTab6.0
Samsung Macbook Notebook    Xtablet iPhone4.7   MacPro  iPadReg GalaxyS4    NSeries7    SamTab9.0   XperiaUltra XTab8.0
Sony    iPad    Gtablet     iPhone5.5   MacBookPro  iPadPro GalaxyS8    NSeries9        XperiaPrem  XTab10.0
```

Comment: posting the csv as text would be an improvement...

Comment: Please add your data as text, explained in details what you are trying to do and add the code you have so far.

Comment: what do you mean by "path"? a `str` object or what?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov yes a str object

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I posted a link to the data

Comment: Link isnt good enough. Paste the actual data as csv as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a homework question, but I found it interesting so here's what I did:

```
csvfile = open('data.csv', 'r') #open the csv file
lines = csvfile.readlines() # read the file into a list, one line per element
headings = [cell.strip() for cell in lines[0].split(",")] #keep a clean list of headings
splitlines = []
for line in lines[1:]: # split each row into cells
    splitlines.append(line.split(",")) 
columns = zip(*splitlines); # convert rows to columns

def recursePrint(colval, text): # a recursive function to traverse the columns
        colval = colval.strip()
        if (colval in headings):
            for c in columns[headings.index(colval)]:
                newtext = text + colval + "->"
                recursePrint(c, newtext)
        else:
            print (text + colval)


for x in columns[0]:
    recursePrint(x, "") # run the recursion
```

And the output:

```
Apple->iPhone->iPhone4.0
Apple->iPhone->iPhone4.7
Apple->iPhone->iPhone5.5
Apple->Macbook
Apple->iPad->iPadMini
Apple->iPad->iPadReg
Apple->iPad->iPadPro
Samsung->Galaxy->GalaxyS3
Samsung->Galaxy->GalaxyS4
Samsung->Galaxy->GalaxyS8
Samsung->Notebook->NSeries5
Samsung->Notebook->NSeries7
Samsung->Notebook->NSeries9
Samsung->Gtablet->SamTab7.0
Samsung->Gtablet->SamTab9.0
Samsung->Gtablet->
Sony->Xperia->Xperia4K
Sony->Xperia->XperiaUltra
Sony->Xperia->XperiaPrem
Sony->Xtablet->XTab6.0
Sony->Xtablet->XTab8.0
Sony->Xtablet->XTab10.0
Sony->
```